# How to Accessing fields from custom search results in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

In the ui, I have created a custom transaction search with vendor lines. How do I access vendor lines values? I have something like this:

```
       var veResults = vendorSearch.run().getRange({
         start: 0,
         end: 50
       });
       for(var i = 0; i < veResults.length; i++)
         {
           var vendorName = veResults[i].getValue({name: 'vendorLine.entityid');
           context.response.write(vendorName); 
         };
```

If I print veResults, I get the following json:

```
  [
{
    "recordType": "vendorpayment",
    "id": "210",
    "values": {
        "employee.entityid": "",
        "trandate": "5/20/2015",
        "print": "Print",
        "type": [
            {
                "value": "VendPymt",
                "text": "Bill Payment"
            }
        ],
        "payrollbatch": "",
        "tranid": "2009",
        "entity": [
            {
                "value": "35",
                "text": "Pacific Bell Telephone"
            }
        ],
        "account": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "text": "1000 Checking"
            }
        ],
        "otherrefnum": "",
        "statusref": [],
        "trackingnumbers": "",
        "memo": "",
        "currency": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "text": "USA"
            }
        ],
        "expectedreceiptdate": "",
        "trandate_1": "5/20/2015",
        "enddate": "",
        "item": [],
        "vendorLine.entityid": "Pacific Bell Telephone",
        "vendorLine.billaddress": "Pacific Bell Telephone\nPacific Bell Payment Center\nSacramento CA 95887-0001\nUS"
    } 
    ...]
```

So, the value is there, how do I get it? The search object has only getValue and getText methods, none of which work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error with this line

```
var vendorName = veResults[i].getValue({'vendorLine.entityid');
```

It should be

```
var vendorName = veResults[i].getValue('vendorLine.entityid');
```

Comment: yes, sorrry my bad - the {} when you use name attribute, which i lacked in my snippet. Like so : var vendorName = veResults[i].getValue({name: 'vendorLine.entityid'});, which is identical to var vendorName = veResults[i].getValue('vendorLine.entityid');. Neither of these work, though.

Comment: try veResults[i].getValue({name: 'entityid', join:'vendorLine'})

Comment: yes, you are correct. The join attribute did the trick, strangely that was one of the first things that I tried, didn't work and moved on onto something else :/ Thank you.